# Python edit multiple worksheets

Tags: python, function, class, worksheet-function

I would like to edit multiple worksheets present in the same Excel File and then save them with the adjustments made. These worksheets have the same columns headers and are called Credit and Debit. The code that I have created is the following:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

class blah:
    def __init__(self, path, file_in, file_out):
        self.path = path
        self.file_inviato = file_in
        self.file_out = file_out
        
    def process_file(self):
        df = pd.read_excel(self.path + self.file_in, sheet_name=None, skiprows=4)
       
        
       ****Here is where I am struggling in amending both worksheets at the same time****
       
       #  df = df.columns.str.strip()
       #  df['Col1'] = np.where((df['Col2'] == 'KO') | (df['Col2'] == 'OK'), 0, df['Col1'])
        



        writer = pd.ExcelWriter(self.path + self.file_out, engine='xlsxwriter')
        
        for sheet_name in df.keys():
            df[sheet_name].to_excel(writer, sheet_name=sheet_name, index=False)
            
        writer.save()

    
b = blah('path....',
         'file in....xlsx',
         'file out.xlsx')


b.process_file()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found a workaround:

```
for sheet_name in df.keys():
            df[sheet_name] = df[sheet_name].rename(columns=lambda x: x.strip())


            df[sheet_name]['Col1'] = np.where((df[sheet_name]['Col2'] == 'KO') | 
                                               (df[sheet_name]['Col2'] == 'OK'), 0, df[sheet_name]['Col1'])
```